# Javascript loop through object keys

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript object

```
const items = {   
   "item 1":{name:'test',vals:[{name:'first',....}]},
   "item 2":{name:'test3',vals:[{name:'second', ....}]}
    //other keys
 }
```

The object keys are dynamic and not just "item 1" and 2 and they keep on changing. I want to access the name property of each object. SO i have done the following by am stuck

```
Object.keys(items).forEach(key=>{
  let keyitem = items.key //am stuck on how to pass the key
 })
```

How do i proceed to the dynamic key as the `items.key` is undefined as there is no such key in the items object.How do i proceed.

Comment: `items[key]` is the syntax you're looking for.

Comment: You could also use Object.entries to get access to the key and value simultaneously: `for (const [key, item] of Object.entries(items)) { ... }`or `Object.entries(items).forEach(([key, item] => ...)`

Answer (score 3):

Replace items.key as items[key]

```
Object.keys(items).forEach(key=>{
  let keyitem = items[key]
 })
```